# FLUTTER: How can we host a flutter module and then integrate it in existing ios project via repository managment?

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

I have a flutter module on my git repository and want to integrate that flutter module as pod in existing ios project.

I tried it using a plugin 'cocoapods=embed-flutter'.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x705a.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.